# How to interact with an several appended childs

Tags: javascript, html

i am creating a todo list as a beginner exercise to train my JS skills but i hit a wall (again). As you can see in my code, i can create tasks that need doing and to each task i appended 2 buttons. Now i want both buttons to do the same thing (remove the task). I would like to create a addEventListener to those buttons but since i created them through JS and not HTML i don't now how to access them or their behavior (i don't know how to get their ID or if they even have one). So my question is this: how can i access those buttons through JavaScript? Thanks.

```js
let b1 = document.getElementById('addItem');
let d1 = document.getElementById('resetList');
let content = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
let Liste = document.getElementById('laListe');

var addTask = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var buttons = document.createElement('button');
  buttons.innerHTML = "X";
  var buttons2 = document.createElement('button');
  buttons2.innerHTML = "Done";
  li.innerHTML = text;
  li.append(document.createTextNode(" "));
  document.getElementById('laListe').appendChild(li).appendChild(buttons);
  li.append(document.createTextNode(" "));
  li.append(buttons2);
}

document.getElementById('addItem').onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
};
b1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addTask();
});



d1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('laListe').innerText = " ";
});


document.getElementById('resetList').onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
};
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Todo.css">
  <title>ToDo App</title>
  <script src='todo.js' defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  <form id="Listcreator" name="itemAdd">
    <input id="listItem" type="text">
    <button id="addItem" type="submit"> Ajouter </button>
    <button id="resetList" type="submit"> Tout Enlever</button>
  </form>

  <ul id="laListe"> </ul>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var buttons = document.createElement('button');
  buttons.innerHTML = "X";
  buttons.addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.parentNode.remove();
  });
  var buttons2 = document.createElement('button');
  buttons2.innerHTML = "Done";
  buttons2.addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.parentNode.remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to your buttons when they are created.

https://jsfiddle.net/cnsxaL3b/

After adding event listeners, your code should look like below:

```
let b1 = document.getElementById('addItem');
let d1 = document.getElementById('resetList');
let content = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
let Liste = document.getElementById('laListe');

var addTask = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var buttons = document.createElement('button');
  buttons.innerHTML = "X";
  var buttons2 = document.createElement('button');

  // Event listener for first button
  buttons.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('clicked button1');
  });

  // Event listener for first button
  buttons2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('clicked button2');
  });

  buttons2.innerHTML = "Done";
  li.innerHTML = text;
  li.append(document.createTextNode(" "));
  document.getElementById('laListe').appendChild(li).appendChild(buttons);
  li.append(document.createTextNode(" "));
  li.append(buttons2);
}

document.getElementById('addItem').onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
};
b1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addTask();
});

d1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('laListe').innerText = " ";
});

document.getElementById('resetList').onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
};
```